# Helpful flags considered good, and declined flags considered bad. What about retracted flags?

Tags: discussion, flags, flag-history, retracted-flags

**Helpful flags** are usually considered good, and **declined flags** are usually considered bad. What about **retracted flags**?

Would a user having many retracted flags make it seem like they are thoughtful, and always retract their flags when an edit has been made to the flagged post, or would it seem like the user made many inaccurate decisions, and corrected them?

I know there are countless reasons why one would retract a flag, but I want to know the general opinion of the community.

*Note: I am aware that only moderators and ourselves can view the amount our retracted flags.*

Comment: depends on who's reading the statistic. (note, only you and mods can see much more than # of helpful flags)

Comment: @user400654 Yes, I am aware of that.

Comment: I'd been wondering this, does it for example count towards a flag-ban, as deleted questions may count towards a question ban.

Comment: A related sub-question would be whether moderators are taught or advised to consider retracted flags when evaluating a user's overall value to the community, e.g. "I wasn't going to Suspend this user just for one dick pic, until I found out that he had 10k retracted flags. That's just way too many. Banned!" Similarly, if a former moderator is applying to get their diamond back, would a large number or percentage of retracted flags be expected to  help, hurt, or have no effect on their application?

Comment: @RobertColumbia I don't know that I've ever looked at a user's flagging history before deciding whether to suspend them or not.

Comment: @Catija You don't know, or you don't think?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Retracted flags, for the purpose of accounting, are neutral. There are too many explanations for why a flag may be retracted for anyone, the system or moderators, to guess at it.

For example someone could retract a flag because:

- They changed their mind about which flag to use and cast a different flag instead after retracting.
- They decided the flag wasn't valid after a while.
- The post was edited to no longer qualify to be flagged - e.g. a link-only answer was edited to contain the content in the answer.
- The user gave up on the flag after a while.
- The user was abusing flags and then decided to retract them after some time.
- The user was just testing how flagging worked and retracted it afterwards.

All of these are possible reasons and some are good - most, in fact - while there are some bad reasons. Having a lot, with no other context just means you have a lot of retracted flags.

That said, if mods happen to notice that someone has a huge number of retracted flags, they might ask about it if it seems odd. That said, I never spent a ton of time looking at users' flag history pages, so the chances a mod would notice or feel like asking is pretty low.

Comment: Can a mod see on a post that I have retracted a flag earlier if I raise a new flag? Or in more general terms: Are there other places except my flag history where a mod can see I have cast a flag that I later retracted?

Comment: Yeah. Mods have a post-level history that shows flags, which includes retracted ones. It's actually the same history page but the mods see more info: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbIX0.png There's also a post flags page but... I don't really use that as much.

Comment: Okay, so if I get really angry at this answer and have 6 to 8 attempts at finding the right tone, I might get suspended 6 times and have one helpful flag. That is good to know ;)